# Conversion with as.date() of csv file false

Tags: r, date, csv

I have a 1gb csv file with Dates and according values. Now is the Dates are in "undefined Format" - so they are diplayed as numbers in Excel like this:

```
DATE     FXVol.DKK.EUR,0.75,4  
38719        0.21825
```

I cannot open the csv file and change it to the date format I like since I would lose data in this way.

If I now import the data to R  and convert the Dates:

```
as.Date( workingfilereturns[,1], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

It always yields dates that are 70 years + so 2076 instead of 2006. I really have no idea what goes wrong or how to fix this issue.

Comment: @akrun I don't think the origin is `1970`, and I don't think that Excel's date is based on epoch time.

Comment: @akrun `Just got the right dupe and duped it` ... um...no, this is not an exact duplicate of that question at all.  In fact, this question would be useful to anyone else trying to import such date data from Excel into R.  You have been marking too many questions duplicate today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note: I have added a note about some quirks in R when dealing with Excel data.  You may want to skip directly to that at the bottom; what follows first is the original answer.)

Going by your sample data, `38719` appears to be the number of days which have elapsed since January 1, 1900.  So you can just add this number of days to January 1, 1900 to arrive at the correct `Date` object which you want:

```
as.Date("1900-01-01") + workingfilereturns[,1]
```

or

```
as.Date("1900-01-01") + workingfilereturns$DATE
```

**Example:**

```
> as.Date("1900-01-01") + 38719
[1] "2006-01-04"
```

**Update:**

As @Roland correctly pointed out, you could also use `as.Date.numeric` while specifying an `origin` of January 1, 1900:

```
> as.Date.numeric(38719, origin="1900-01-01")
[1] "2006-01-04"
```

**Bug warning:**

As the asker @Methamortix pointed out, my solution, namely using January 1, 1900, as the origin, yields a date which is two days too late in R.  There are two reasons for this:

- In R, the origin is indexed with 0, meaning that `as.Date.numeric(0, origin="1900-01-01")` is January 1, 1900, in R, but Excel starts counting at 1, meaning that formatting the number 1 in Excel as a Date yields January 1, 1900.  **This explains why R is one day ahead of Excel.**
- (Hold your breath) It appears that Excel has a bug in the year 1900, specifically Excel thinks that February 29, 1900 actually happened, even though 1900 was not a leap year (http://www.miniwebtool.com/leap-years-list/?start_year=1850&end_year=2020).  As a result, when dealing with dates greater than February 28, 1900, **R is a second day ahead of Excel.**

As evidence of this, consider the following code:

```
> as.Date.numeric(57, origin="1900-01-01")
[1] "1900-02-27"
> as.Date.numeric(58, origin="1900-01-01")
[1] "1900-02-28"
> as.Date.numeric(59, origin="1900-01-01")
[1] "1900-03-01"
```

In other words, R's `as.Date()` correctly skipped over February 29th.  But type the number `60` into a cell in Excel, format as date, and it will come back as February 29, 1900.  My guess is that this has been reported somewhere, possibly on Stack Overflow or elsewhere, but let this serve as another reference point.

So, going back to the original question, the origin needs to be offset by 2 days when dealing with Excel dates in R, where the date is greater than February 28, 1900 (which is the case of the original problem).  So he should use his date data frame in the following way:

```
as.Date.numeric(workingfilereturns$DATE - 2, origin="1900-01-01")
```

where the date column has been rolled back by two days to sync up with the values in Excel.

Comment: There is an `as.Date.numeric` method. If these are Excel dates, the examples from the documentation are very relevant.

Comment: I have now noticed that R converts "38719"  to  "2006-01-04", however, according to excel it is "2006-01-02". Any idea? 

I now solves it by as.Date.numeric(workingfilereturns[,1]-2, origin="1900-01-01").

Comment: @Roland
So i should use as.Date.numeric(workingfilereturns[,1], origin = "1899-12-30") ?

Comment: @Roland Thanks again for the input.

Comment: Or just quote R's documentation: `## Excel is said to use 1900-01-01 as day 1 (Windows default) or
## 1904-01-01 as day 0 (Mac default), but this is complicated by Excel
## incorrectly treating 1900 as a leap year.
## So for dates (post-1901) from Windows Excel
as.Date(35981, origin = "1899-12-30") # 1998-07-05`